# Remove menus and submenus

Tags: admin-menu

So I found some handy snippets to help remove admin menu items. However, I'm having trouble with the sub menu items. I want to keep the appearance menu, but get rid of the Themes, Widgets, and Editor.

```
function remove_menus()
{
global $menu;
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if($current_user->user_login == 'username')
{
    $restricted = array(__('Posts'),
                        __('Links'),                     
                        __('Comments'),
                        __('Plugins'),
                        __('Users'),
                        __('Tools'),    
                        __('Settings')

    );
    end ($menu);
    while (prev($menu)){
        $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
        if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted))
       {unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
    }// end while
    }// end if
    }
    add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');

function remove_submenus()
{
global $menu;
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if($current_user->user_login == 'username')
{
    global $submenu;
    unset($submenu['themes.php'][10]); // remove the theme editor
}
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_action('_admin_menu', 'remove_editor_submenu', 1);
function remove_editor_submenu() {
    remove_action('admin_menu', '_add_themes_utility_last', 101);
}

add_action('admin_init', 'remove_theme_submenus');
function remove_theme_submenus() {
    global $submenu; 
    unset($submenu['themes.php'][5]);
    unset($submenu['themes.php'][7]);
    unset($submenu['themes.php'][15]);
}
```

To disable other submenu names, go to ./wp-admin/menu.php and search for the item(s) you want to disable.

EDIT: As far as disabling by username, I would instead add a new capability to a role and use that as your removal condition [see here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8083/plugin-to-remove-admin-menu-items-based-on-user-role). Otherwise, just use what you already were using, like so:

```
add_action('_admin_menu', 'remove_editor_submenu', 1);
function remove_editor_submenu() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if($current_user->user_login == 'username') {
        remove_action('admin_menu', '_add_themes_utility_last', 101);
    }
}

add_action('admin_init', 'remove_theme_submenus');
function remove_theme_submenus() {
    global $submenu, $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if($current_user->user_login == 'username') {
        unset($submenu['themes.php'][5]);
        unset($submenu['themes.php'][7]);
        unset($submenu['themes.php'][15]);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: If the themes submenu is disabled, the Appearance top-level menu simply becomes a mirror of the next available submenu. So with all the submenus except for "Menus" disabled, "Appearance" now becomes the same as the "Menus" submenu.

Comment: NICE! It worked like a charm. How do I make it so it only effects the user I name like in the snippet where I took out several menus. Sorry for so many questions, thx for the help.

Comment: [Look here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8083/plugin-to-remove-admin-menu-items-based-on-user-role) to find out how to add a new capability to a role and use that as your removal condition.

Comment: And here is a more in-depth explanation of the method @Milo explained using `remove_menu_page()` and `remove_submenu_page()`: [http://sethstevenson.net/customize-the-wordpress-admin-menu-based-on-user-roles/](http://sethstevenson.net/customize-the-wordpress-admin-menu-based-on-user-roles/)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't know about this site till now. Thanks guys. I will read up on how to do everything. Thanks again for all the answers and code.

Answer (score 2):

There are much simpler functions for removing menu and submenu pages since 3.1:

[remove_menu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page) and [remove_submenu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page)

however, the issue with removing themes is that the appearance menu IS the themes page.

EDIT- what you can do is remove the entire appearance menu, then create a new top level menu item using [add_menu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

```
function wpse31255_add_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( __('Nav Menus', 'mav-menus'), __('Nav Menus', 'nav-menus'), 'edit_themes', 'nav-menus.php', '', 99 );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpse31255_add_menu_page');
```

Comment: I added it to my functions.php and it is not working. Thanks for the tip about the remove_menu_page() and remove_submenu_page() functions. On the first code snippet I tried it with __('Appearance'), and without it.