# Wordpress Remove Submenus

Tags: admin, user-roles, admin-menu, capabilities, sub-menu

I found an answered question here [Remove menus and submenus](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31255/remove-menus-and-submenus) **2 Answers** for my problem but is there a way of changing the code a bit so that it removed the submenus for all Editor roles. not only for one user? and is there a way of improving this code? I am using `3.5.1` version of WordPress

**code that I am using:**

```
add_action('_admin_menu', 'remove_editor_submenu', 1);
function remove_editor_submenu() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if($current_user->user_login == 'username') {
        remove_action('admin_menu', '_add_themes_utility_last', 101);
    }
}

add_action('admin_init', 'remove_theme_submenus');
function remove_theme_submenus() {
    global $submenu, $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if($current_user->user_login == 'username') {
        unset($submenu['themes.php'][5]);
        unset($submenu['themes.php'][7]);
        unset($submenu['themes.php'][15]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all occurrences of `$current_user->user_login == 'username'` with `in_array('editor', $current_user->roles)`. And you can remove the call to `get_currentuserinfo();` as for the user information is available from the global variable `$current_user`.

Here's a code swap:

```
add_action('_admin_menu', 'remove_editor_submenu', 1);
function remove_editor_submenu() {
    global $current_user;
    if(in_array('editor', $current_user->roles)) {
        remove_action('admin_menu', '_add_themes_utility_last', 101);
    }
}

add_action('admin_init', 'remove_theme_submenus');
function remove_theme_submenus() {
    global $submenu, $current_user;
    if(in_array('editor', $current_user->roles)) {
        unset($submenu['themes.php'][5]);
        unset($submenu['themes.php'][7]);
        unset($submenu['themes.php'][15]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`user_can`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can).

```
if (user_can($current_user->ID,'editor')) { ...
```

I don't know which of the two functions you want that in but is should be simple to replace or add to your existing `if` conditional.

You say "Editor roles"-- plural-- but I am assuming you mean "all users who are in the Editor role".