# User role and capablities only for 1 plugin

Tags: user-roles, admin-menu, capabilities

What if i want a user called Marketing *only* to see the Slimstat plugin? The rest of the admin menu should be invisible for him.
(for a external marketing agency that should see our stats but only our stats)

Comment: That should be possible, yes. You'd need to check which capabilities that plugin tests to show the menu and display stats.

Comment: I think this post will help you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8083/plugin-to-remove-admin-menu-items-based-on-user-role. Please check.